# allow position relative & top until the div is touching top of page

Tags: html, css

I have aligned a `div` element (`.xasi-modal__login-modal`) within my page to the middle using `vertical-align`, along with a slight offset of `-40px` from the top, using `position: relative`.

It works, however, when `.xasi-modal__login-modal` reaches / touches the top of the page, it disappears above it. Is there a way to make it so that when `.xasi-modal__login-modal` "touches" the top of the page, the `top: -40px` is disabled through **CSS** or **JS** (preferably CSS)?

This is the basic **HTML** & **CSS**:

```css
.modal-login__align{
  display: table-cell;
  height: 390px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.xasi-modal__login-modal{
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
  width: 340px;
  height: 390px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-login__align">
  <div class="xasi-modal__login-modal"></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vde3pwtL/

Thanks.

Comment: what you really trying  to achieve?

Comment: @dreamhunter `Is there a way to make it so that when the div "touches" the top of the page, the top: -40px is disabled through CSS or JS (preferably CSS)?`

Comment: can you show us a demo , or fiddle

Comment: @JishnuVS check the new edit :)

Comment: yes i've checked the fiddle, there is a redbox and inside there is a empty div with relative position

Comment: @JishnuVS great! :) you're on the correct fiddle then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to detect `max-height`.

We can calculate the `max-height` value by taking the modal's `height` and adding double the negative `top` (because we're vertically centered)

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vde3pwtL/2/)**

**CSS**

```
@media (max-height:470px){
    .xasi-modal__login-modal{
        top:0;
    }
}
```